# HERE Maps Distance to Destination always returns high Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api, here-ios

I had calculated a route in here maps and started Turn-by-Turn Navigation using that route. Everything is working fine in offline and when i tried to calculate the distance to reach the destination using

```
double distance = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;
```

The above method returned value which is very high such as 184467440737095520000. The returned value is always 184467440737095520000 even for different routes. when i referred the navigation manager delegate i found that this method will return values in metres. But even this returned value is too high of my destination's distance..Please guide me how to calculate the distance to my destination correctly..  thanks in advance

```
-(void)CalculateRoute:(NMARoutingMode *)routingMode
{

routeManager = [NMARouteManager sharedRouteManager];
routeManager.delegate = self;
NSMutableArray* stopList = [NSMutableArray array];
[stopList addObject:_StartCoordinate];
[stopList addObject:_DestinationCoordinate];

NSLog(@"routing from [%.5f,%.5f] to [%.5f,%.5f]", ((NMAGeoCoordinates*)stopList[0]).latitude, ((NMAGeoCoordinates*)stopList[0]).longitude,
      ((NMAGeoCoordinates*)stopList[1]).latitude, ((NMAGeoCoordinates*)stopList[1]).longitude);
NSLog(@"routingMode===>%@",routingMode.description);


[routeManager calculateRouteWithStops:stopList routingMode:routingMode];
 }


-(IBAction)StartNav:(UIButton*)sender
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(positionDidUpdate)
                                             name:NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePositionNotification

                                           object:[NMAPositioningManager sharedPositioningManager]];
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].map = self.mapView;
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].delegate = self;
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingAutoZoomEnabled = YES;
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingEnabled = YES;
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingOrientation = NMAMapTrackingOrientationDynamic;
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].speedWarningEnabled = YES;
[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].mapTrackingTilt = NMAMapTrackingTilt2D;
[[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager]startTurnByTurnNavigationWithRoute:_route];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error when computing the distance. The value **184467440737095520000** is equal to the **NMANavigationManagerInvalidValue** constant.

Try to compute the distance when your position is updated, so do it in your *positionDidUpdate* method as you mentioned:

```
double distance = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;
```

If you would like to do it the first time after calling the *startTurnByTurnNavigationWithRoute* method, you should get such information from the route:

```
double distance = _route.length;
```

Btw, if you try to do the same with the timeToArrival, you will get a high value too.

Answer (score -1):

`distanceToDestination` is **not** a `double` value. It is an `unsigned long long` value or `NMAUint64` value.

Do following:

```
unsigned long long distance = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;
```

or

```
NMAUint64 distance = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;
```